# I'm trying to extract data in the tag <a data-params> from Amazon.com website

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have set of Amazon URLS ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LTIORC8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LTIORC8)) in column A in excel and Im trying to extract "B00M4L4MFC" data from " href="/dp/B00M4L4MFC/ref=dp_cerb_1"" in column B using the below html tag.

```
                            <a data-params="/gp/cerberus/log/click/mid/ATVPDKIKX0DER/asin/B01LTIORC8/sub/B00M4L4MFC/pos/1/dev/WEB" class="a-link-normal cerberus-asin" href="/dp/B00M4L4MFC/ref=dp_cerb_1">
```

I found the below code online :

```
Sub GetAboutUsLinks() 
Dim internet As Object
Dim html As Object
Dim myLinks As Object
Dim myLink As Object
Dim result As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim LastRow As Integer

Set internet = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Loop through all the web links on the worksheet one by one and then do some things
For i = 2 To LastRow
'Get the link from the worksheet and assign it to the variable
myURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
'Now go to the website
internet.navigate myURL
'Keep the internet explorer visible
 internet.Visible = True
'Ensure that the web page has downloaded completely
While internet.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend
'Get the data from the web page that is in the links and assign it to the 
 variable
 result = internet.document.body.innerHTML
'create a new html file
Set html = internet.document
MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML
'CreateObject (“htmlfile”)
'now place all the data extracted from the web page into the new html document
 html.body.innerHTML = result
 Set myLinks = html.getElementsByTagName(“a”)
'loop through the collected links and get a specific link defined by the conditions
For Each myLink In myLinks
If Right$(myLink, 9) = "ref=dp_cerb_1" Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = myLink
End If
'go to the next link
Next myLink
'once the last web link on the sheet has been visited close the internet explorer
If i = LastRow Then
internet.Quit
End If
'go to the next web link on the worksheet
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If the ASIN number from that link is your only requirement to grab then you can fetch the same using `xmlhttp` request. That should be way faster than IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already downloaded the data (and you have it is sitting in the cells of your sheet) then you do not need to fire up the browser (nice syntax there by the way, `GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")`, I will blog that!)

See this [blog post](http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2017/12/use-mshtml-to-parse-local-html-file.html) for opening HTML already downloaded and parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try. . .

```
Sub GetAboutUsLinks()

Dim internet   As Object
Dim html        As Object
Dim myLinks   As Object
Dim myLink    As Object
Dim result      As String
Dim myURL    As String
Dim LastRow  As Integer

Dim varAuxMyLink As Variant
Const LNG_INDEX_POSITION_ToGetMyLink = 2
Const STR_BREAKING_CHARACTER = "/"

Set internet = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop through all the web links on the worksheet one by one and then do some things
For i = 2 To LastRow
    'Get the link from the worksheet and assign it to the variable
    myURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value

    'Now go to the website
    internet.navigate myURL

    'Keep the internet explorer visible
     internet.Visible = True

    'Ensure that the web page has downloaded completely
    While internet.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'Get the data from the web page that is in the links and assign it to the
     variable
     result = internet.document.body.innerHTML

    'create a new html file
    Set html = internet.document
    MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML

    'CreateObject (“htmlfile”)
    'now place all the data extracted from the web page into the new html document
     html.body.innerHTML = result
     Set myLinks = html.getElementsByTagName(“a”)

    'loop through the collected links and get a specific link defined by the conditions
    For Each myLink In myLinks
        If Right$(myLink, 9) = "ref=dp_cerb_1" Then
            ' Transform the string in an Array/Vector
            varAuxMyLink = VBA.Split(myLink, STR_BREAKING_CHARACTER)
            ' Check if variable is an Array
            If VBA.IsArray(varAuxMyLink) Then
                                                     ' Get thirth element of Array / Vector
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = varAuxMyLink(LBound(varAuxMyLink) + LNG_INDEX_POSITION_ToGetMyLink)
                ' Restart de variable
                Let varAuxMyLink = Empty
            End If
        End If
        'go to the next link
    Next myLink

    'once the last web link on the sheet has been visited close the internet explorer
    If i = LastRow Then
        internet.Quit
    End If
    'go to the next web link on the worksheet
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: I tired this but this doesn't enter the value "B00M4L4MFC" in the adjacent column to the Amazon URLs in Excel.. need additional help or new code.